# Love2d adding value to table inside for loop.. Using a variable

Tags: lua, love2d

This is something that's really been nagging at me for some time:

```
for i = 1, 4 do
   x = love.physics.newFixture(diffTable[i].body, diffTable[i].shape):setCategory(10)
   x = x:setUserData('Border') -- error here
   table.insert(data, x)
end
```

Let's say I want to insert a variable into the table (basically creating the variable, and then modifying it) and then inserting it:

When I do the `x = x:setUserData(...)` an error comes up.. saying **attempt to index global variable x (nil)**

So my question is, how would I create a variable inside a for loop, specifically
I need to do it this way because I'm using `love.physics`, and creating a `fixture` with a category. I also need to `setUserData` at that time but it's not possible.

And I'm sure there has to be a way of doing this...
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you specify what your expected and actual outcome is? Like, do you want `data.x` to be the same value as `x`? Or do you want `data[1] = { x = x, y = y }` (that's what your first line with `table.insert` would do)?

Comment: data.x = x.....

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense. what do you want to achieve? improve your post. the provided code is full of errors and it does not help to show whwat you want to do. improve it

Comment: @codeRdevelopR if you expect that result then you shouldn't be using `table.insert`. `table.insert` will put the value at the next numeric index available. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.insert https://www.lua.org/pil/19.2.html

Comment: Yes I've changed the question slightly.. its more detailed :)

Comment: `Fixture:setCategory` doesn't return anything. https://love2d.org/wiki/Fixture:setCategory so you are setting `x` to `nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [Fixture:setCategory](http://love2d.org/wiki/Fixture:setCategory) does not return a value.

so when you do this

```
x = love.physics.newFixture(diffTable[i].body, diffTable[i].shape):setCategory(10)
```

you are setting `x = nil`.
[Fixture:setUserData](https://love2d.org/wiki/Fixture:setUserData) also does not return a value.

If you change it to this you will no longer get that error.

```
for i = 1, 4 do
   x = love.physics.newFixture(diffTable[i].body, diffTable[i].shape)
   x:setCategory(10)
   x:setUserData('Border') -- error here

   table.insert(data, x)
end
```

Comment: Looked into `setUserData` just now it also does not return a value.

Comment: @codeRdevelopR that's why you should always refer to manuals. programming is not some magic power. it basically boils down to reading documentations.

Comment: This is very true, in fact, I really dont know anything about love2d I just looked up the function you were using to set the value of `x` in the love2d documentation, as the simplest answer to why `x = nil ` is that the function returns nothing.